# How to list source code file names at Java run time?

Tags: java, list, file, dynamic

When my program starts to run, how do I list available java source file names ? For example, I have a few dozen source files named "My_App_*.java" in my src directory, after I start my app, how can I call Java to list source files start with "My_App_" dynamically ?

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where the source directory is:

```
File srcFolder = new File("./src");
String[] files = srcFolder.list();
for(String file : files){
    if(file.startsWith("My_App_")){
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new File(".").list(new FilenameFilter()
{
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
  {
    return name.startsWith("My_App_") && name.endsWith(".java");
  }
});
```

Replace . with the directory where the files are.

But why do you need to do that?

Comment: Why ? Because my program dynamically generated some java source files, and at the time of programming, I don't know what they might be called besides the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Use [java.io.File.list](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list) and its related methods. You can either get a `String[]` of filenames, or `File[]`. You can provide a `FilenameFilter` or a `FileFilter`, or you can filter the returned array afterward.